# How create a function method on FBJS that reference 'this' as HTML element?

Tags: facebook, fbjs

have tried to use this my own function on FBJS:

```
function addEvent(event,fun,pars){
pars.event=event;
pars.listen=function(){ fun(this, pars);return false; };
this.addEventListener(event,pars.listen,false);
}
```

but dont work...if call:

```
obj=document.getElementById("id_element");
obj.addEvent(....);
```

Firebug return this error:am123456789_obj.addEvent is not a function

Any idea to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create the `addEvent` function as a property of the object, so you can't call `obj.addEvent()`.  The object simply doesn't know about that function.

With FBJS, your best bet is to simply pass the object in as a parameter.

```
function addEvent(obj,event,fun,pars){
pars.event=event;
pars.listen=function(){ fun(obj, pars);return false; };
obj.addEventListener(event,pars.listen,false);
}

obj=document.getElementById("id_element");
addEvent(obj,...);
```

Comment: Yes, already used this method, I thought of changing it to get more elegant code...but if is not possible click undo on Netbeans :) Much Thanks Zombat